# IIS option "Unlisted File Extensions are not allowed" filtering all servlet calls to WebSphere

Tags: iis, websphere, iis-8.5

We are running IIS 8.5.9600.16384 with Windows 2012 R2, with IIS routing URLs that map to servlets to a WebSphere Application Server 8.5 instance. In IIS, we have configured a web server instance, where it serves static files from the disk, at the same time the IIS-WAS connector ensures URLs that call the Java server are routed properly. This configuration is running correctly with no issues.

As part of our security hardening process we need to enable the "Unlisted File Extensions are not allowed" option, however it ends up blocking URLs that should be routed to our WAS server. We added a white list of allowed extensions  (htm, html, js, xml, etc), along with a period (".") - which was recommended on stackoverflow. The files from the static site are being served properly, but IIS is still blocking all the servlet application calls.

Is it possible to enable this option for this configuration? Or is IIS truly unable to route extensionless-URLs to WAS when this option is enabled?

Comment: There is no restriction on file extensions for the routing to WAS but URL matching occurs based upon your plugin-cfg.xml. If your applications contain mappings that contain extensions, your plugin configuration will be matching the extensions also.  Examples: *.jsp (extension matched) /servlet/* (extension not matched)

Comment: none of our servlet paths have extensions, all of the are the "/servlet/XXXXX" variety. the routing works fine if the config is turned off, so I'm confident the plugin-cfg.xml is working (at least for the non-hardened config)

Comment: Are there any new errors or messages in the IIS or plugin logs with the hardened config?

Comment: yep we looked out for those as well, but nothing was being written down. I'm not sure if we're missing any logging config for this?

Comment: You could change the WAS plugin loglevel to Debug or Trace to see if IIS is passing the requests to the plugin filter (and maybe even if plugin is passing some response back to IIS). This is the only thing I can think of to help find the root cause.